# Which algorithm does Blender use to bake normal maps?

Tags: normal-map

I am studying Computer Science and have to prepare a presentation about normal mapping in Blender. 
While I can find a lot about how I can do it in blender, I could not find anything about which technic/ algorithm is used. 
Does anyone know how Blender bakes the normal maps? 
I found another link where the standard approach for normal mapping is explained, but I am not sure if this is used in Blender (Link below). 
Thank you for the help in advance.

https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch22.html

Comment: The beauty of it is that Blender is open source software, you can directly check out it's source code and know how it actually works.